# remove carriage return and line feed while pasting sql rows in Excel

Tags: unix, sybase, aix, carriage-return, linefeed

Hi right now I am fetching some data from sybase sql and whatever data I get paste it in a excel sheet and send a mail. The problem is all the columns and their values don't come in a line. I need  it arrange this in a line.

I did a bit of research for this and found it is happening because of carriage returns and line feed. I am fetching rows using the * field and not specific column.

`sed "s/\r\n/g" $LOG > temp_log.txt`

Used above command but to no use.  What would be the best way to remove the carriage returns. Code samples appreciated with some explanation. Thanks

Comment: If it is bash: `sed $'s/[\r\n]//g' "$LOG" >temp_log.txt` if not bash: `sed $(printf 's/[\r\n]//g') "$LOG" >temp_log.txt`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After the first comment I noticed the original question.
The problems were caused by a previous step. In the previous step lines were folded by isql. Repairing the damage will be very hard, since it is difficult to predict which lines should be pasted together as one record.
The original problem can be taken away by telling isql to put more data on 1 line: `isql -w 2000`.
When you just want to find out out to join lines together, you can use `tr` (use `sed` for line operations). 
Joining all lines together is possible with

```
cat $LOG | tr -d "\r\n" > temp_log.txt
```

When $LOG is some path/file with spaces, the above command will fail. And perhaps get used to writing your own variables in lowercase and use braces for variables:

```
cat "${log}" | tr -d "\r\n" > temp_log.txt
```

The tr is looking for the single characters, nut for the combination of them, so it will also delete a single `\n`.

And when you want to avoid `cat`, improve this to

```
tr -d "\r\n" < "${log}" > temp_log.txt
```

When you know what the total length of all columns are, you can try `fold -w totallength` after the `tr`, but that will only work when isql has padded all fields with spaces (not tabs) to the total length.

Comment: It seems that after trying  all your  suggestions, The results are now getting attached all in one line..even the columns and their values.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted. When you want all headers in one line and each record also on one line, try using `isql -w 2000` for expanding the linelength in the output.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Please modify the answer before I mark it right.

Comment: I also added a remark about `fold -w recordlength`, but fixing `isql` is clearly better.